# How would I know where to find specific documentation?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

Edit - [Solved]

So recently I have been learning how in integrate MySql Database to Visual C so I tryed finding the documentation to better understand each line of code. I ended up finding its on the MySql website but does not go into much detail.

I then found out through other users questions that some/most of the methods used are actaully inherited from a base interface/class

Example: IDataReader  - is the base class
Then programs would inherit from it then make things such as XmlReader and MySqlDataReader

Which can be found here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.aspx

### Now here is where my questions starts

How would I have known/figured out where to start looking? If someone did not link me to the exact URL spot how would I have **navigated microsofts site to find it in the first place**?

What is a ".NET framework" and how would I have known that integrating a database would use it? - It says its Window Based so does that mean **different operating system** have there own ".Net framework"?

Is it safe to assume if we are **trying to combine different applications** together they have to have something binding them together hence need of ".Net framework"

Comment: While I understand your frustration, this question is also too broad and open-ended for Stack Overflow.  My recommendation is to continually drill into each topic until you understand its purpose, then move on to the next.  It is the nature of the business and the sooner you develop the necessary research skills, the better off you'll be and the more you'll enjoy it.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN (Microsoft Developer Network) is the umbrella in which all (or at least very most) Microsoft documentation lies.  However, this is a huge conglomeration of information, and navigating it is not really an easy thing to give step-by-step instructions for, or even a general overall approach.

What you're facing is a large part "general learning curve", and the other part is a skillset for finding answers, usually starting with google and often ending at StackOverflow or MSDN or various blogs.  In time, as the skill grows (and it is very much a skill), you will learn to be skeptical of articles based on various clues, and learn to tell upon reading them whether the author really knew what they were doing (Microsoft's articles themselves aren't without some measure of this variance in quality).  Some sites become known as "stay away, they teach bad practices"

"Google-Fu" is an unofficial term that some people use to describe how well they can coerce google into returning relevant information.  Often times it's easy, and often times it's quite difficult.

In short, there's no clear answer.  Research is a skill to be honed, not unlike programming itself.  Start as you are and keep pushing forward, and eventually you'll get a feel for it and get good at it.